# как сделать компонент дисклеймер

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Как сделать вот такой компонент на react native?
Причем чтобы иконку в дальнейшем можно было бы переместить по пропсу в любой угол?

Проблема в том, что независимо от разрешения слова должны врапаться, и во вложении я прикрепил, что рядом с иконой 2 строчки потом переваливается вниз весь оставшийся текст [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Получается примерно так

```
<View>
     <Text>
       <Image
         style={{
           width: 40,
           height: 40,
           borderRadius: 20
         }}
         // Please. use the correct source =))
         source={require('image.jpg')}
       />
       Тест тест тест тест тест Тест тест тест тест тест Тест тест тест тест
       тест Тест тест тест тест тест Тест тест тест тест тест
     </Text>
</View>
```

Если как компонент оформить:

```
const Disclaimer = ({ text, imageSource}) => {
 return (
    <View>
      <Text>
       <Image
         style={{
           width: 40,
           height: 40,
           borderRadius: 20
         }}
         // Please. use the correct source =))
         source={imageSource)}
       />
       {text}
     </Text>
    </View>
 )
}
```

Но в данном случае будет только в одну строку картинка и текст, если прям как нарисовано, то нужно костылить под конкретный текст, покажу абстрактно без некоторых обязательных опций:

```
<View>
    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
       <Image/> 
       <View>
          <Text>Тут текст в две строки</Text>
       </View>
    </View>
    <Text>продолжение текста</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, что независимо от разрешения слова должны врапаться, и во вложении я прикрепил, что рядом с иконой 2 строчки потом переваливается вниз весь оставшийся текст

Comment: надо это описать в проблеме

Comment: все равно не так получается, текс сразу переходит под иконку

Comment: @user451829 странно, специально собрал по быстрому на эмуляторе, получается как на скрине

Comment: может какие то стили еще нужно прописать?

Comment: @user451829 немного сглупил в впопыхах, вам же 2 строки чтоб было надо, так к сожалению без костылей не получится